# setting data to class attributes

Tags: class, oop, attributes

I'm a newbie to software designing.
I have created a class(DTO) **User** which contains 20 attributes with accessory methods.
This object has to be updated into DB table.
I have to set data to User object using setter methods.

To do this, do I need to call 20 setter methods or is there any standard alternative approach?
Can a class(DTO) contain more attributes?

Here is my class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Responsing to your direct question, the answer is - there is no standard approach. All options are open, a getter/setter per Att, exposing them as private data members and accessing directly, creating on or more interfaces that channel the access to them even more, etc. All depends on other aspects of your system and its design.

DTO can contain any number of attributes you wish. It is another question if this is ok.

Even without seeing your concrete example, I dare to suspect that this DTO could be broken in several smaller ones.

Make some further analysis on it. Is it possible to break it using inheritance? Them using composition structures? And finally maybe even normal associations.

It is always better to have more smaller and wisely related elements, that to have one large blob-object. The whole OO paradigm is all about better class design.

If you post the details of your DTO (name and atts) I might give you some ideas on refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have DTO class. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Using setters is very common. Another way is to declare a constructor, which initializes the object in a single call, but 20 arguments seems way too many for that. Depending on the way the User object is initialized, a [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) may come useful to you. You should also take a look at your table and see if maybe you can decompose it further using [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), this way you may be able to end up with smaller tables. If you still end up having to initialize a large amount of fields in you object, consider using a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) to shorten your code.